# How to make schedule for slider images in Wordpress

Tags: slideshow

I am new in WordPress. I want to set up a display schedule for slider images. I couldn't find any keyword about this.

Does WordPress have a feature like this? How to implement it? Thanks

Comment: please use revolution slider  and search free slider plugin for wordpress

Comment: donload plugin url :https://www.themesfreedownload.top/slider-revolution-v5-4-7-3-responsive-wordpress-plugin/

Comment: Does it support schedule? I couldn't find any  information

Answer (score 0):

i hope solve your problem this plugin please try :

1] https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-banners/

2] https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-custom-header-images/

3] https://www.wp-tweaks.com/change-the-header-image-per-page-wordpress/

4] https://wordpress.org/plugins/unique-headers/

5] https://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-slider-3/

Comment: Thank you, But I forgot that I need a slide feature but this plugin doesn't have with free version

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work in my case. I need a plugin or solution that can help me make slider images and schedule these images